# Do USB to PCI and PCI-E adapters exist?

Tags: laptop, usb, pci-express, pci, minipci

I have the intention of connecting an assortment of different PCI and PCIe cards to my laptop. Obviously laptops don't have PCI or PCIe ports.

Is there any adapter out there which will allow me to connect a PCI or PCIe card to my laptop via USB?

I have seen ones which go from Mini PCIe to full PCIe through a USB3 cable, but I believe this does not use a standard USB pinout, and my laptop also only supports USB2.

Thanks for any replies.

Comment: USB 2 to PCI-E adapters do not exist.  USB 2 does not have enough bandwidth.

Comment: Actually some laptops do have PCIe ports, they are called "ExpressCard", see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExpressCard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is **not** Possible.

However, some laptop brands have the possibility to add some components. Look if there is any Slot available by opening every possible traps under/on the side of your laptop. If there is, do some researches on `How to add a PCI Component` or find an online Manual of your laptop and read about this specific part.

I'd like to apologize if some things are not clear in what I just said, english is not my first language. Feel free to edit my post if you can find a better way to explain this. :)